# Swift: Remove keys and values added during array flatMap conversion

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

Trying to make array of dictionaries with object, which adds keys and values during array flatMap

```
var parameters: [String: Any] {
var postParameters: [String: Any] = [:]
postParameters["topics"] = categories.flatMap({ toPostParameters($0) })
print(postParameters)
return postParameters
}


private func toPostParameters(_ topics: Topics) -> [String: Any] {
var params: [String: Any] = [:]
params["id"] = topics.id
params["isFound"] = topics.isFound
return params
}
```

when I print the *postParameters* value, all I get is like the following. How to remove the key and value strings appending over it.

```
["topicCategories": [(key: "isFound", value: true), (key: "id", value: "62ef2b63e49a"), 
(key: "id", value: "632serer269"), (key: "isFound", value: true)]]
```

Expected

```
["topicCategories": [["isFound": true, "id": "62ef2b63e49a"], 
["id": "632serer269","isFound": true]]]
```

Comment: So what exactly is it what you want then? Could you add an example?

Comment: It seems like you want `map` rather than `flatMap`...

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I need to have output without those key and value

Comment: So an array of tuples then or? Why can't you add an example?

Comment: @Sweeper seems *map* gets the job done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use map, because `flatMap` makes everything "flat" and you get a flat array of tuples instead of array of dictionaries.

---

### Example:

```
class Topics {
    var id = 1
    var isFound = true
}

var categories = [Topics(), Topics(), Topics()]

var parameters: [String: Any] {
    var postParameters: [String: Any] = [:]
    postParameters["topics"] = categories.map({ toPostParameters($0) })
    return postParameters
}


private func toPostParameters(_ topics: Topics) -> [String: Any] {
    var params: [String: Any] = [:]
    params["id"] = topics.id
    params["isFound"] = topics.isFound
    return params
}

print(parameters)
```

---

### Output:

```
["topics": [["id": 1, "isFound": true], ["id": 1, "isFound": true], ["isFound": true, "id": 1]]]
```

---

### P.S:

Good [article](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/map-flatmap-and-compactmap/#:%7E:text=One%20way%20of%20performing%20such,new%20values%2C%20using%20a%20transform.&text=So%20map%20transforms%20an%20array,into%20just%20a%20single%20array.) to understand the difference between `map`, `compactMap` and `flatMap`.

Comment: I've changed my answer a bit, to make it more clear. Thanks @JoakimDanielson.